# TSQL: Dynamic value for TOP

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have a need to allow users to query all or some records. Right now I am doing this:

```
DECLARE @Limit INT = NULL

IF @Limit IS NULL SELECT @Limit = COUNT(ID) FROM vwNotifications

SELECT TOP (@Limit) ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Type, CreatedBy DESC) AS Row, Title
FROM vwNotifications
```

Is there a way I can do this without using the `COUNT` query?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you have two options

1 make top something like 2 billion if it is 0
but then again..do you really want to return 2 billion rows in 1 shot?

```
DECLARE @Limit INT = NULL

SELECT @Limit = COALESCE(@Limit, 200000000)

SELECT TOP (@Limit) ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Type, CreatedBy DESC) AS Row, Title
FROM vwNotifications
```

or do an if else

```
DECLARE @Limit INT = NULL

IF @Limit IS NULL

SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Type, CreatedBy DESC) AS Row, Title
FROM vwNotifications

else

SELECT TOP (@Limit) ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Type, CreatedBy DESC) AS Row, Title
FROM vwNotifications
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your table will never contain more rows than supported by an integer (i.e. Primary key is an `int` rather than a `bigint`, which in practice is likely):

```
DECLARE @Limit INT = NULL 

IF @Limit IS NULL OR @Limit = 0
   SET @Limit = 2147483647  -- Max Int

SELECT TOP (@Limit) ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Type, CreatedBy DESC) AS Row, Title 
FROM vwNotifications
```

Your other option is an if statement and two queries..